# Git LFS Track Folder With Code

Tags: git, git-lfs

What happens when I set Git LFS to track a folder which contains both code and images?

I have a `Resources` folder where I hold images (`jpg`, `png`, `ico`, etc.) and XML for UI configurations like a `ResourceDictionary` for XAML with my colors, brushes, icons paths and etc.

Will Git stop tracking the XML and act as it was a binary file instead?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, git lfs internal now manages the text file more or less like binary, i.e, storing the whole version instead of just the delta.